# Example of finite measure and infinite measure

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Give an example of infinite measure $\nu$ and finite measure $\mu$ on reals such that $\nu ≪ \mu$, and for each $δ > 0$ there is an interval $I ⊂ R$
satisfying $\mu(I) < \delta$ and $\nu(I) ≥ 1$

My attempt:

$d\mu = f dx, d\nu = g dx$ with different positive $f, g$. This was given as a hint but I do not know how to proceed with this.

I know such an example is impossible if $\nu$ is finite from Theorem 3.5 in Folland's real analysis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done with scaled Lebesgue measure - take $\nu$ to be the usual measure on the line, and define $\mu$ by scaling so that

\begin{align*}
\mu([0, 1]) &= 1 \\
\mu([1, 2]) &= \frac 1 2 \\
\mu([2, 3]) &= \frac 1 4
\end{align*}

and so on (and likewise for the other side of the line). Now every set with $\mu$ measure zero has $\nu$ measure $0$.

---

If you prefer to deal with densities directly, take $g \equiv 1$ and $f$ any $L^1(\mathbb{R}$) function.

Comment: Can you please explain the part "take $g \equiv 1$ and $f$ any $L^1(\mathbb{R}$) function" . I can see it relates to the hint but how does this serve as an example that we are looking for?

Comment: That means to take $g$ a constant function, and $f$ literally any (nonnegative) function whose associated measure is finite.

Comment: I can see it relates to the hint but how does this serve as an example that we are looking for?

Comment: @Silvermoon Well, did you try actually working with these measures? Can you find an interval whose measures are, say, respectively $\mu(I) < 1/2^{100}$ and $\nu(I) \ge 1$?

Comment: This is where I am facing problem. I cannot understand how this is possible when ν≪μ, Any suggestions please?

Comment: I am actually trying to work with Analysis on my own, so having these issues

Comment: @Silvermoon How are you understanding $\nu ≪ \mu$? Absolute continuity is about having common sets of measure $0$.

Comment: To my understanding if meausre of $\mu$ goes to zero, so does the measure of $\nu$, isn't it correct?

Comment: @Silvermoon It depends on your definition, but the simplest phrasing is "all sets of $\mu$ measure zero have $\nu$ measure $0$." Read the definition [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_continuity#Absolute_continuity_of_measures).

Comment: So can you please explain the question you posed "μ(I)<1/2100  and ν(I)≥1"?

Comment: @Silvermoon I am asking whether you can find an interval with this property, based on the definitions of $\mu$ and $\nu$ (this can be done with an interval of the form $[n, n + 1]$ if you choose $n$ well).

Comment: Oh ok, I understand, thanks